# JavaScript I am pushing data to array but can't get newly pushes data from array

Tags: javascript

here is my axois response data which I am passing to array

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "room_id": "sasdfdfdfa@gmail.com",
      "id": 7,
      "created_at": "11 July Tuesday 2023 05:57 PM",
      "message": "usdadssdasdarcc"
    },
    {
      "room_id": "sasdfddssfdfa@gmail.com",
      "id": 8,
      "created_at": "11 July Tuesday 2023 05:57 PM",
      "message": "fdsf"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access the id of every item like this `console.log("newly pushed dta",dataArray.data.map((data)=>(data.id)))` but you can see the consle.log error

[image]

my axois data is added to the array but why can't access it?

my code

```
const dataArray = [
    {
      avatarSrc: 'https://themes.mintycodes.com/quicky/assets/media/avatar/2.png',
      name: 'Catherine Richardson',
      time: 'Just now',
      message: 'I didn’t catch that. Could you please repeat?'
    },


    {
        avatarSrc: 'https://themes.mintycodes.com/quicky/assets/media/avatar/2.png',
        name: 'Catherine Richardson',
        time: 'Just now',
        message: 'I didn’t catch that. Could you please repeat?'
      },
    
     
    
    // Add more objects as needed
  ];


axios.get('http://localhost:8000/chat/',{ withCredentials: true })
  .then(response => {
     
    dataArray.push(response.data);
    console.log("dataAray",dataArray)
    console.log("newly pushed dta",dataArray.data.map((data)=>(data.id))) //here trying to access id of each data array
     
    }) 
   
    

 
  
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  })
```

Comment: Because `dataArray` is an array, and arrays have no property called `data`?

Comment: @David how can I access the newly added axois data from my array?

Comment: Well, if `dataArray` is an array, and you want to call `.map()` on that array, it would look like: `dataArray.map(/*...*/)`.  It looks like adding `.data` was just a typo?  There are *so many things* in this code named "data" that you seem to be confusing yourself with it.

Comment: @David I tried `console.log("newly pushed dta",dataArray.map((data)=>(data.data.map((data)=>(data.id)))))` but didn't work

Comment: What *specifically* are you trying to access?  `dataArray` is an array of objects.  One of those objects has a property called `data`, which is also an array.  (You see how this is getting confusing?)  Are you looking for `dataArray[2].data.map()`?  (Of course you'd need to change this if the element you're looking for ever *isn't* at index `2`...)  (And of course having an array of objects with drastically different structures is just asking for problems...)

Comment: @David thanks it's working. can u explain why it's not working `dataArray[2].map((data)=>(data.id))) ` which is Victor answer but ur code is working

Comment: That one isn't working because `dataArray[2]` is not an array, so you can't call `.map()` on it.  It's *very important* that you observe and understand the data structures you're using, don't just radomly try things until something doesn't produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

Since dataArray is array you cannot reach dataArray.data. You must use index of array's element to get that element in array

```
dataArray[2].data.map((data)=>(data.id)))
```

this will work

Comment: yeah, sorry I missed that your axios response is an object. Edited my reply